# How to edit a Minecraft player's message on the server using Java only for specific players?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I am developing a plugin that implements chat censorship for those who have it enabled. For instance, I've set up a ban word, and for player A, it appears uncensored, while for player B, who has the mode enabled, it gets replaced with ***.

I'm facing an issue with how to edit messages only for specific players. I specifically want to edit the message, not cancel the chat event and then send a new message on behalf of the server. Doing so would make other plugins like Chatty unable to detect and log the modified message. I attempted to use ProtocolLib, but the required function returns NULL and behaves incorrectly.

```
protocolManager = ProtocolLibrary.getProtocolManager();
protocolManager.addPacketListener(new PacketAdapter(this, ListenerPriority.HIGHEST, PacketType.Play.Server.CHAT) {
    @Override
    public void onPacketSending(PacketEvent event) {
        logger.info("Packet received, passing through checks");
        if (event.getPlayer() == null || !event.getPlayer().isOnline())
            return;
        if (!event.getPlayer().hasPermission("nbw.filter") || !event.getPlayer().hasPermission("nbw.auto")){
            return;
        }
        logger.info("Checks passed!");
        final StructureModifier<WrappedChatComponent> chatComponents = event.getPacket().getChatComponents(); // This damn thing doesn't return anything if the message lacks 'special tags' like purple coloring, not sure how to fix the code above
        // I don't know how to fix the code above
        logger.info("Getting chatComponents: " + event.getPacket().getChatComponents());

        for (WrappedChatComponent component : chatComponents.getValues()) {
            logger.info("FOR - Starting");
            if (component == null){
                logger.info("component = null");
                continue;
            }
            logger.info("Checking passed, proceeding line by line");
            //component.setJson(component.getJson().replace("#star#", "☆"));
            String lowercaseMessage = component.getJson().toLowerCase();
            logger.info("lowcasemess successful");
            String end = component.getJson();
            logger.info("lm = " + lowercaseMessage + "\n\nEnd: " + end);
            event.getPlayer().sendMessage(end);

            for (String bannedWord : bannedWords) {
                logger.info("GG");
                String lowercaseBannedWord = bannedWord.toLowerCase();
                if (lowercaseMessage.contains(lowercaseBannedWord)) {
                    end = end.replaceAll(bannedWord, "*".repeat(bannedWord.length()));
                }
            }
            component.setJson(end);
            logger.info("END: " + end);
        }
    }
});
```

I think the issue lies in this line
`final StructureModifier<WrappedChatComponent> chatComponents = event.getPacket().getChatComponents();`
it doesn't return anything if the message lacks 'special tags,' such as purple coloring (I discovered this thanks to the uwuchat plugin).

Initially, I was just sending messages on behalf of the server, and it seemed to work, but plugins like Chatty wouldn't detect those messages. I expect my plugin to take precedence in processing player messages. After handling and replacing the necessary words with ***, it should then pass the message to cosmetic plugins for further processing.